# Replace element of table inside struct variable (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, date, struct

Is it possible to replace certain element of table inside struct variable? I use this syntax, but it gives me an error message.

```
    File.Jan.Date(1,1) = Date2(1,1);
```

Here Date2 is 1x1 table and File.Jan.Date is a 70082x2 table.

Here is the error message:

> The following error occurred converting from datetime to cell: Error
>   using cell Conversion to cell from datetime is not possible.

I try a simpler example like this:

```
Date=datestr('02/02/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')
Date = datetime(Date,'InputFormat','MM/dd/yyyy');
Date.Format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
T = table(Date,'VariableNames',{'Date'})
T(1,1)=Date
```

And gives me error message below

> Right hand side of an assignment into a table must be another table or
>   a cell array.

Comment: Is `File.Jan.Date` a cell array?

Comment: File is  1x1 struct variable containing Jan which is 1x1 struct variable too. Inside Jan, I have Date which is 70082x2 table. This Date was extracted from excel file with ''mm/dd/yyy'' date format.

Comment: Possibly related to a problem discussed in [UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/solving-a-matlab-mcos-bug).

Comment: Does replacing the parentheses with curly braces help? e.g. `File.Jan.Date{1,1} = Date2(1,1);` for the first example or `T{1,1}=Date` for the second. MATLAB's table columns have two types: a numeric array if it's homogeneous numeric data or a cell array if it contains mixed data types

Answer (score 0):

With Matlab tables, you can reference the column by name, and then reference the row by index.  So for your smaller example, you can do the following:

```
T.Date(1) = Date;
```

For your original question, if File.Jan.Date is a table, I'm guessing one of the variables of the table is a datetime?  Then you can do the following (assuming it is named DateField):

```
File.Jan.Date.DateField(1) = Date2.Date(1);
```